# How to make Gmail open when clicking mailto: links in the same browser it is clicked? (Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, email, gmail

I just installed 12.04 and when clicking `mailto:` links Thunderbird opens.

I want Gmail to open in the browser, in which `mailto:` was clicked.

- So if I am in Firefox and click a `mailto:` link a new FF tab should with Gmail should open.
- And if I am in Chrome, a new Chrome tab should open accordingly.

Is there a way to do this via some script? Or would I need to set this in some system settings?

Answer (score 49):

You can make Chrome open when you click a `mailto:` link:

> Access [Gmail](https://gmail.com), and click an icon of the shape of overlapped double
>   diamonds, next to the star icon in the omni-box where the URL is
>   displayed.
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt7wJ.png]
>
> If you don't see it, try reloading the page.

*[Source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/33951/114995), by [mulogics](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/27453/mulogics) on Web Applications Stack Exchange*

If you somehow missed the opportunity and said 'no' after the diamond question, your chance to undo that is under `chrome://settings/handlers`, where gmail will be listed as *handler-question-blocked*.

Comment: If the diamonds don't appear there is also this option: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler

Comment: @nedned I seem to have broken my configuration trying to test that. I unset the handler in Chrome and followed the instructions, but when the popup appeared, I accidentally closed it. Now I've tried everything but I can't get it back.

Comment: @nedned I was just digging through my Chrome settings when I noticed Gmail was blocked from becoming an email handler. (In Settings -> Content settings -> Handlers.) Not sure how exactly that happened, but I got it working now!

Comment: after removing from the blocked list. Refresh your Gmail, it again asks this time click 'Allow'.

Answer (score 29):

There is an option for that in firefox.

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Applications -> mailto
```

or

```
Firefox menu -> Options -> Options -> Applications -> mailto
```

[image: Firefox Options Page]

Comment: This should be marked as the "accepted answer" assuming that OP is using the currently default Firefox browser with Ubuntu.

Comment: we should merge this answer with the answer above, both are useful.

Answer (score 15):

`gnome-gmail` lets you do exactly that.

This is what reads from the Description section in the control file of `gnome-gmail` package.

> support for Gmail as the preferred email application in GNOME

To install `gnome-gmail`, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-gmail
```

After installing, open `gnome-gmail` and adjust your settings.

However, if and when you click on the `mailto:` links, it will open a Gmail tab in the preferred browser instead of whichever browser you are currently in.

Comment: I'm getting an error: Access blocked: Viagee's request is invalid. Error: 400: invalid_request

Answer (score 2):

#### As of Ubuntu 14.04, [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler) did the job under Chrome:

1. Open [your Gmail account](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox)
2. Open the Javascript console. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>)
3. In the Javascript console, enter:

   ```
   navigator.registerProtocolHandler(
       "mailto",
       "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s",
       "Gmail");
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you should get the confirmation popup to approve.

This needs to be repeated for each browser profile you have.