# Why I can't make Google Chrome open "mailto" content type?

Tags: google-chrome, 18.10

I want to make Google Chrome default mail app, in other word I want to make Google Chrome to open "mailto" content type like Firefox as mentioned [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/182495/758020) in my Gmail in Google Chrome. 
Also I have gone to "Settings > Details > Default Application" to make Google Chrome default Mail application, but it is not available in the Mail list. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with modern websites offering "service handlers". First, make sure you allow service handlers in Chrome, then allow Gmail to use its service handler.

1. In Google Chrome, open Settings,click Advanced, and under Privacy and Security, click on Content Settings.
2. Click on "Handlers" and set the option "Allow sites to ask to become default handlers for protocols" to "on".
3. Go to Gmail and log in.
4. You will see a new symbol in the URL bar. It looks like a double diamond. Click it.
5. Set "Allow mail.google.com to open all email links?" to Allow.

Comment: The option was enabled for me in the settings already, but I still can't enable it on any mail service... no double diamond...

Comment: Did not find content settings in latest chrome build, not even in the global settings search, weird.

Comment: I just had to go to my gmail tab, click the double diamond and choose Allow. Thanks.